# how to call uwp class library in win32 C++ console application

Tags: c++, winapi, uwp

I wanna call a uwp app with Uri in a win32 C++ console application.The first thing I thought is using LaunchUriAsync, but I couldn't find Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync in win32 C++. So I wanna create a uwp class library to call LaunchUriAsync  and win32 call this library. I find an example and now I can load the library sucessfully, but GetProcAddress always returns null. Not sure whether it is feasible calling uwp class library in win32 console. Pls help me out. The project is at https://github.com/vincent1000/win32CallUwpLibrary
The code is very simple:

**UWP Classy Library:**

```
namespace ExportedCodeSolution 
{
public class Class1
{
    [DllExport(ExportName = "callUri", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    static public async void callUri()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("call URI start");
        await Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("www.bing.com"));
    }
}
}
```

**And Win32 Console:**

```
using CallUriFn = void(__stdcall*) ();
int main()
{
HMODULE mod = LoadLibraryA("ExportedCodeSolution.dll");
CallUriFn fn = reinterpret_cast<CallUriFn>(GetProcAddress(mod, "callUri"));
fn();
}
```

Also, **is any other method to call LaunchUriAsync in win32?** I have searched some methods but none works for me.

Comment: If this is going to work (and not sure if it can) you will need to use a __declspec(dllexport) exported function like from any normal native DLL, that function will forward to the static CallURI method. The native side doesn't know anything about the DllExport attribute.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is trivial: Simply call [Launcher.LaunchUriAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.system.launcher.launchuriasync) from your console application. The easiest route is to use [C++/WinRT](https://aka.ms/cppwinrt). Assuming that you are using Visual Studio with the [C++/WinRT extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=CppWinRTTeam.cppwinrt101804264) installed, create a *"Windows Console Application (C++/WinRT)"*, and replace the wizard generated code with this:

```cpp
#include <winrt/Windows.Foundation.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.System.h>

using namespace winrt;
using namespace Windows::Foundation;
using namespace Windows::System;

int main()
{
    init_apartment();

    Uri uri(L"www.bing.com");
    Launcher::LaunchUriAsync(uri).get();
}
```

This will compile, but fail at runtime due to `"www.bing.com"` not being a valid URI. This needs to be replaced with a valid URI (e.g. `"https://www.bing.com"`).